# Find $gcd({a^2} , {b^3})$, knowing that $gcd(a,b)=4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find  $gcd({a^2} ,  {b^3})$, knowing that $gcd(a,b)=4$

I tried looking at the problem expressing $a=4k$ and $b=4j$ for some $j,k$ and that means that $a^2=16k^2$ and $b^3=64j^3$ and thinking of $16$ and $64$ as the boundaries of the $gcd(a^2,b^3)$ and after taking some examples such as $gcd(4,12)=4$ and computing $gcd(16, 12^3)$=16 and other examples as well. I am almost convinced that the answer is 16. Is there any suggestion how to start the solution in a more analytical approach?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\gcd(a,b)=4$, then $4\mid a$ and $4\mid b$.  Moreover, either $8\nmid a$ or $8\nmid b$.

- If $8\nmid a$, then $4$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $a$.  Then $16$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $a^2$.  Since $4\mid b$, we know that $16\mid b^3$, so $16$ divides both $a^2$ and $b^3$, no other primes can divide both $a$ and $b$ since otherwise they would show up in the original gcd and $16$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing both $a^2$ and $b^3$.  Therefore, $16$ is the gcd in this case.
- If $8\mid a$, then $8\nmid b$.  Then $64$ divides $a^2$ and $64$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides both $a^2$ and $b^3$.  Following the argument from above, the gcd is $64$.

Answer (score 2):

Doing that is impossible.

Notice that if $a=0$ and $b=4$ then $gcd(a,b)=4$ and $gcd(a^2,b^3)=4^3$.

Notice that if $a=4$ and $b=0$ then $gcd(a,b)=4$ and $gcd(a^2,b^3)=4^2$.

Comment: great point, mister, do you have any suggestion which can help me with the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be decomposed uniquely as a product of prime factors; we have then: 
$$a=\prod_i^N p_i^{\alpha_i}, \,\,\,\,\; b=\prod_i^N p_i^{\beta_i}  \;\;\; \Rightarrow gcd(a, b) = \prod_i^N p_i^{min(\alpha_i, \beta_i)}
$$
(Since a divisor must cannot have greater multiplicity in any prime factor). So, we have:
$$gcd(a^2,b^3) = \prod_i^N p_i^{min(2\alpha_i,3\beta_i)}
$$
From, this, it is easy to get a counterexample for your case, for example, if $\alpha_1 = 3$ and $\beta_1 = 2$:
$$ gcd(8, 4) = 4, \;\;\; \text{but} \;\;\; gcd(8^2, 4^3) = 64 \neq 16
$$